Using RAM from multiple nodes in cluster
I have with 10 million embeddings which are 1536 dims long. I'm fairly confident this means I need less than 128 GB of memory. I'm running Milvus using EKS on AWS and have 2 m6i.4xlarge machines which have 64 GB of memory each, meaning I should have plenty of memory.
Now, as I understand it, a collection must be partitioned such that it can be loaded onto multiple machines at once (https://milvus.io/docs/manage-partitions.md). Therefore, I introduced a partition key (https://milvus.io/docs/use-partition-key.md):
fields = [
            FieldSchema(name="id", dtype=DataType.VARCHAR, max_length=24, is_primary=True),
            FieldSchema(name="embedding", dtype=DataType.FLOAT_VECTOR, dim=VECTOR_DIMENSION),
            FieldSchema(name="document", dtype=DataType.VARCHAR, max_length=30000),
        ]

        schema = CollectionSchema(
                fields,
                description="Vector store collection for arxiv",
                partition_key_field="document",
                n_partitions=16
        )

        milvus_collection = Collection(name=MILVUS_COLLECTION_NAME, schema=schema)

Then I added entries and indexed
index_params = {
        "index_type": "IVF_FLAT",
        "metric_type": "L2",
        "params": {"nlist": 1024}
    }
    milvus_collection.create_index(field_name="embedding", index_params=index_params)

and tried to load the collection:
milvus_collection.load()

However, it only makes it to 38%  when I get the following error:

pymilvus.exceptions.MilvusException: <MilvusException: (code=65535,
message=show collection failed: load segment failed, OOM if load,
maxSegmentSize = 1576.6993761062622 MB,  memUsage = 55411.66015625 MB,
predictMemUsage = 56988.35953235626 MB, totalMem = 63273.46875 MB
thresholdFactor = 0.900000)>

Why am I only able to use one machines RAM? Is there a way to check where each partition is stored and how big it is? Trieed looking on github but couldn't find anything.

This is answered in the Milvus Discord Community
https://discord.com/channels/1160323594396635310/1272946645017034937/1272946645017034937
yhmo | Zilliz — Yesterday at 4:08 AM
The "document" max_length is 30000, which looks like for long-length text content?
When you call collection.load(), the query nodes try to load the 3 fields into memory.
For "embedding" field, it loads the index into memory.
For "document" field, it loads the text content into memory.
Let's say the average length of "document" is 10000, which means each row has a 10KB text. For 10M rows, the total size of "document" is 10KB * 10M = 100GB.
The total size of "embedding" is 1536 * 4B * 10M = 60GB.
100GB + 60GB > 128GB.
yhmo | Zilliz — Yesterday at 4:20 AM
The advantage of partition key is: when you do a filtering search on a partition key field, the partition key will accelerate the search performance.
For example:
I have 3 fields "id", "embedding", "flag". The "flag" field has many possible values from 1 to 1000.
I define the "flag" field as partition key, milvus will create some partitions, and automatically distribute different rows to different partitions according to the hash value of the "flag" field value.
I want to search with filtering the "flag" filed: collection.search(expr="flag == 8" ...), milvus can quickly find the partition which stores the rows of "flag = 8", it only searches this partition so that the performance is high.
So, if you don't need to do filtering search on the "document" field, no need to set it as partition key.
The basic data model of Milvus is: a collection can contain multiple partitions, a partition can contain multiple segments.
If a collection has only one partition, all the segments are managed by this partition. The query nodes can balance memory usage for these segments.
An optional solution to reduce memory usage is:
Enable mmap for the collection: https://milvus.io/docs/manage-collections.md#Set-MMAP

release collection first collection.release()
Set memory mapping property to True or Flase collection.set_properties(
properties={
    "mmap.enabled": True
} )


With mmap enabled, milvus will use mmap api to load the "document" field to save memory.
Manage Collections | Milvus Documentation
Manage Collections | v2.4.x
yhmo | Zilliz — Today at 12:09 AM
Two possible reasons:
The Mivlus cluster you deployed only has one query node. All the data is loaded into this query node and the node can only access 64GB RAM of one ec2 instance.
The Milvus cluster has 2 query nodes. But the "document" field has lots of long-length text which is also loaded into memory, both query nodes almost run out of memory.
